# Ansible error of var type when passing to my custom module

Tags: python, module, ansible, roles, molecule

I'm looking to make an ansible role and module abled to list all packages on a Linux System actually installed and register them to a var.
Then upgrade all of them and put the second list in an other var.

My module is here to make a diff of the two dictionaries (yum_packages1 and yum_packages2) and return it at the end of my role

When i'm trying to pass thoses two dictonaries into my modules and start my treatment i have a very strange error.

> fatal: [centos7_]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument yum_packages2 is of type  and we were unable to convert to dict:  cannot be converted to a dict"}

Ansible role task

```
---
# tasks file for ansible_yum_update_linux
- name: Listing Linux packages already installed
  yum:
    list: installed
  register: yum_packages1

- name: Upgrade paquets Linux
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    exclude: "{{ packages_exclude }}"

- name: Listing Linux packages installed and updated
  yum:
    list: installed
  register: yum_packages2

- debug:
    var: yum_packages1
- debug:
    var: yum_packages2

- name: file compare
  filecompare:
    yum_packages1: "{{ yum_packages1.results }}"
    yum_packages2: "{{ yum_packages2.results }}"
  register: result

- debug:
    var: result
```

Custome ansible module

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule

def diff_update(f1,f2):
    #f3 = set(f1.keys()) == set(f2.keys())
    upd1 = set(f1.values())
    upd2 = set(f2.values())
    f3 = (upd1.difference(upd2))
    return f3

def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec = dict(
            yum_packages1 = dict(required=True, type='dict'),
            yum_packages2 = dict(required=True, type='dict')
        )
    )

    f3 = diff_update(module.params['yum_packages1'],module.params['yum_packages2'])

    module.exit_json(changed=False, diff=f3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Do you have any idea why i get this error ?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Can you edit your question and add the full (well at least with a view of all ran tasks and the structures of the 2 vars) playbook output ? Furthermore, do you really need to have a custom module for this ? 
The [`difference` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) seems to do exactly the same job.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any idea why i get this error ?

Because `set` is not json serializable:

```py
import json
print(json.dumps(set("hello", "kaboom")))
```

cheerfully produces:

```
TypeError: set(['kaboom', 'hello']) is not JSON serializable
```

That's actually bitten me a couple of times in actual ansible modules, which is why I knew it was a thing; if you insist on using your custom module, you'll want to convert the `set` back to a `list` before returning it:

```
module.exit_json(changed=False, diff=list(f3))
```

Comment: so returning objects i.e. instances of classes isn't really possible with Ansible, I'm assuming anything that has to return an object should not be a module in the first place and returning objects or instances of classes is bad design ?  Just curious as this didn't seem like it was worth a separate question, thanks in advance !